# cq5: Where to find the code of the versioning and Diff in geometrixx-outdoors site?

Tags: aem, jcr

In the geometrixx-outdoors site I can do some change in the site and then create new version (sidekick -> versioning -> create version). I can also restore old versions and compare with the curretn version.

Can somebody tell me where can I find the functions in the geometrixx-outdoors code, which do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not in geometrixx -- use CRXDE to look under libs:  /libs/wcm/core/content/tools/timewarp ../version  ../restore   etc.

Comment: Thanks for answering but  /libs/wcm/core/content/tools/timewarp is empty.